# Playing sounds in WPF app using MediaPlayer

Tags: c#, wpf

I wanted to play sounds in WPF app using MediaPlayer. The problem is that I can't use the file directly from resources file like in SoundPlayer

```
SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(R.testSound);
```

So I used path to sound like this:

```
mediaPlayer.Open(new Uri("../../Resources/testSound.wav", UriKind.Relative)); //working
mediaPlayer.Open(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/testSound.wav")); //not wroking
```

Is there any possibility to do this without a relative path? Is Relative path bad idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you register to the MediaFailed event, you will see that it returns a message that says "System.NotSupportedException: Only site-of-origin pack URIs are supported for media."

**Solution**

1. Edit your testsound.wav's Build Action to "Content" and "Copy Always".  This is needed for site-of-origin solutions.
2. Use "siteoforigin" pack URI instead of "application" when you open the media player.  Here's working code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace SoundTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        MediaPlayer mp;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        }

        private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Dispatcher called");
                mp = new MediaPlayer();
                mp.MediaOpened += Mp_MediaOpened;
                mp.MediaFailed += Mp_MediaFailed;
                mp.Open(new Uri("pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/testsound.wav"));

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{ex.GetType()}: {ex.Message}\n{ex.StackTrace}");
            }
        }

        private void Mp_MediaFailed(object sender, ExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            var ex = e.ErrorException;
            Console.WriteLine($"MEDIA FAILED: {ex.GetType()}: {ex.Message}\n{ex.StackTrace}");
        }

        private void Mp_MediaOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mp.Play();
            Console.WriteLine("Play called");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just one question. I created a setup/installer and after installation in an app, I don't hear music. How I can add these sound files to the installer?

Comment: You will need to give me more info. I have no idea what kind of installer you created or where you got it or what your installer code looks like.  I'm running blind here.

Comment: I used Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects. I made installer in this way: https://youtu.be/mTkh3sgh6tI?t=41

Comment: In the video, Step 3 shows that you can specify the Primary Output of your project to be included. This should automatically include your "Resources/testsound.wav" file. To verify if this is true, build your installer, run the installer, and then check your installation folder to see that it contains your .exe as well as the "Resources/testsound.wav" file. If it doesn't, then you will probably have to do Step 4 from the video and add the file manually, and specify the directory where you want to install it. If that doesn't work, you're better off opening a new stackoverflow question for this.